# Payment processor for PayTrace

Tags: extension, payment-processor

Has anyone looked into or done any dev work on a payment processor extension for PayTrace?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that if you googled and found nothing then either the answer is no, or if it has been done then it is fairly unlikely that a question here will drag that information forth. happy to be proven wrong and def. worth asking ;-) just didn't want to leave this without any answer/comment, since no answer may be the outcome since a lot of us could say 'no' without being sure of our facts, and only the actual developers/uses, if they exist, could say 'yes.

Comment: I agree with Pete - but I'll also note that there's support in OmniPay for PayTrace.  Since there's (highly) experimental support for OmniPay in CiviCRM, I think that's the easiest path if you want to get this working.